# In Java, read a row from excel ,write it in an existing csv file and then update the MySQL table from this csv

Tags: excel, csv, apache-poi, ibatis, mybatis

I want to read a row from an excel sheet and then append it to the end of an existing csv file. Finally, from this CSV file, the database table in MySQL needs to be updated.

I am able to read the values from excel using Apache POI and print it in the console of eclipse. But confused how to append the row to the end of an existing CSV file. And then this inserted row also needs to be inserted into a table in MySQL.

Comment: Why do you need the workaround via the CSV file? Why don't you generate directly the sql updates?

Comment: When you asked the question in that way, somebody will simply suggest you to write to a PrintStream, but I think basic I/O is not your problem ... so you need to clarify what your real problem is. Is it a sparse table, where not all columns of every row are filled, so you need to generate empty csv values? Or do you need to apply a special formatting for numbers,date,user-specified fields for your csv?

Comment: I apologise. there was a mistake in the requirement. I have edited my question. It was written column in place of row.
Explanation:- Whenever I add a new row to the excel, this row should get appended at the end of the CSV file. There would be some existing records in the CSV. I want the appending to take place at the end of these records in a new row. The columns in both the excel and the CSV will be the same, say name ,designation and salary. Its just that whenever I add a new row in the excel, this should get appended towards the end of ths CSV file upon running the program. standalone appl

Comment: please provide the piece of code for this .. how to handle this ..this is my first hurdle. Next will be to update the database..

Answer (score 0):

You may use a CSV library such as Super CSV (http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/) to read and write the CSV file

Answer (score 0):

http://techblog.ralph-schuster.eu/csv-utility-package-for-java/ provides all you might need for that: JDBC, Excel and CSV access.